c# itextSharp unicode in form fields
I fill a pdf Form with c# (itextSharp). I have one text field and set value with a string containing unicode chars. After saving the pdf, the Unicode chars are not displayed, but if I enter in field with cursor (to edit it), the text looks correct. If I leave the field, the Unicode chars are not displayed. If I made any change in field (adding a space, for example) the text looks AND remains correct.

Could you provide specific version, and code sample, because we can't help without any information how the pdf was created

also, what software do you use to see your pdf ? Have you tried several (e.g. : adobe reader ? webbrowsers like firefox and chrome ?)

Usually form fields are defined to be filled in with a specific font with a specific encoding. As often that encoding in WinAnsiEncoding or something similar. PDF viewers then usually use a replacement font of their choice for characters outside that encoding upon fill-in. A library can do so, too, but if the replacement does not work as desired, the user of an interactive viewer can still intervene while a program filling in a form using some library cannot double-check. Thus, such replacement mechanisms in PDF libraries are a bit dangerous.

Nonetheless, PDF libraries often do implement such mechanisms, and many iText versions do, too. To help you with details, though, we'd need to know the specific iText variant and version you use, and you should provide example code and form to help helping you.

Thanks for your answers; in the end it works with:
string fontPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(cale, "segoeui.ttf");
BaseFont unicodeFont = BaseFont.CreateFont(fontPath, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
....
pdfStamper.AcroFields.SetFieldProperty(camp, "textfont", unicodeFont, null);
In PDF, the font was already Segoe UI.
And for previous results, I was using Adobe Reader, Foxit Pdf Reader and Firefox browser.
